# xml to querystring

Tags: ruby, xml, url, post

What is the best option to generate a querystring (url params) from an XML document in Ruby ?

```
xml_string = <abc><session>1234</session><description>some_description</description></abc>

query_string = # I want here "?abc=session......."
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `?session=1234&description=some_description`? The URL parameters are flat, e.g. only have one level, while your XML has two levels.

Comment: are you using rails or active_support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xml_string = "<abc><session>1234</session><description>some_description</description></abc>"
result = "?"+Hash.from_xml(xml_string).to_query
```

Answer (score 0):

XmlSimple is a nice gem.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xmlsimple'

data = XmlSimple.xml_in(xml_string)
url_params = xml_to_url_params(data, "abc")


def xml_to_url_params(xml_data, root)
  elements = []
  data[root].each do |item|
    item.each do |name, value|
      elements << "#{CGI::escape(name)}=#{CGI::escape(value)}"
    end
  end
  elements.join("&")
end
```

ps. did not tested this code, so there can be bugs ;)